# sudo ./ : command not found

Tags: command-line, sudo

http://youtu.be/8oYTrf9jnGk  for a video i made of it in action.

N.B. - I have my nvidia .run file on my desktop - I double click it, and it appears to run but stops asking for sudo permissions.

So I open a terminal and attempt to run it via a *sudo sh [file]* and *sudo ./[file]* but both give *file not found*

if you can help fix this? then please do!

Comment: wow, someone edited this to be nothing like the original question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The File seems to be in your Desktop, so you first have to `cd Desktop` (or whatever its called in your language) before trying to run it. Try it and please inform if you succeed. This answer may change based on your results.

Thank you and Good Luck!

Comment: ahhh, lol, good eye!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sudo su`, and running the script afterwards. Did you set `chmod +x` ?

Comment: This was my issue. For some reason sudo says "command not found" instead of "file not executable" -- this is a bug in linux